# PHP: Inserting the current timestamp into SQL Server 2005

Tags: php, sql-server

How do I insert a current_timestamp into an SQL Server 2005 database datable with a timestamp column?

It should be simple but I cannot get it to work.  Examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

if you can execute a query from PHP then it should just be a matter of using 'getdate()' ;

```
update MyTable set MyColumn=getdate();
```

or

```
insert into MyTable (MyColumn) values (getdate());
```

Comment: I didn't realise that there was a 'current_timestamp' function now too - getdate() was what we used back in SQLS6. current_timestamp is much clearer, I think. 

Despite the name, getdate() does return a timestamp, not just the date.

Answer (score 6):

The column datatype should be datetime

You can either get the database to work out the date:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tablename (fieldname) VALUES (getdate())';
```

or get PHP to work out the date

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tablename (fieldname) VALUES (\'' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '\')';
```

then something like `mssql_execute($sql);` but this depends on how you are connecting to your database

Answer (score 3):

To insert data into a timeStamp field, I think you have to use `DEFAULT`.
For example:

```
INSERT INTO User(username, EnterTS) VALUES ('user123', DEFAULT)
```

where `EnterTS` is a TimeStamp field

Answer (score 2):

You just use the normal mechanism to execute your queries into SQL Server, and use what follows.

The current_timestamp function returns it

```
 insert into table (creation_date) VALUES (current_timestamp)
```

Complete example

```
CREATE table timestamp_test (creation_timestamp datetime)
INSERT INTO timestamp_test (creation_timestamp) VALUES (current_timestamp)
SELECT * FROM timestamp_test
DROP TABLE timestamp_test
```

Answer (score 0):

If you explain the error you are receiving (and post your insert or update code), it might make it easier to see what your problem is. One possible issue is that you must be inserting into a datetime field (or in 2008 you could use a date field as well). Occasionally people think that they can insert the current date into a timestamp field but even though the name of this data type seems as if it should be date related, this data type actaully has nothing to do with dates and times and cannot accept date data.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post but I ran across this and figured others might too.

What I do is to create a field in the table using the datatype of datetime and then for the column properties for the default Value or binding, I enter `getdate()`.  Every record that gets entered into the table now has a date and time stamp.